# Is it possible to decrement a HyperLogLog set in Redis

Tags: redis, hyperloglog

Let's say that i have a hyperloglog in redis which counts messages is there any provisions whereby I can to some degree account for delete messages?

Comment: Would it be reasonable to create two hyperloglog sets? `messages.created` and `messages.deleted` and just assert the decrement?

Comment: The two hyperloglog sets way **MIGHT** be a solution. It depends on your scenario. For example, it cannot solve the following scenario: add an element, delete the element, and then add the same element again. Can you give us more details on your scenario?

Comment: @for_stack Yeah i mean that'd make sense. Although not sure i'd ever create the _same_ element again - as recreating a previously deleted message would have a new UUID.

Comment: Another solution might be to just recreate the HLL and `PFADD` the entire dataset. But that becomes less and less feasible with the size of the HLL :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the HyperLogLog doesn't support the concept of deletion. Instead, use a different counter (could be an integer, Set or HyperLogLog) and subtract the totals.